# RegSetValueEx returns 998, REG_SZ

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

return_value is 998, what corresponds ERROR_NOACCESS, invalid access to memory location. What is the problem? Memory is allocated correctly, pointer is correct

```
LPWSTR path = VirtualAlloc(0, MAX_PATH*2, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE); 
GetModuleFileNameW(0, path, MAX_PATH); 
HKEY key;
RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &key);
int return_value = RegSetValueEx(key, RandName(), 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)path, 0); 
RegCloseKey(key);
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but `ERROR_NOACCESS` may also be returned when you don't have the appropriate access/permission to modify the selected registry key.

Comment: Might want to read [Registry Key Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-key-security-and-access-rights)

Comment: I run the program as administrator and other keys gives same error

Comment: @AdrianMole no. `ERROR_NOACCESS` have nothing common with access/permission. this is 100%. the 3 errors converted to this - `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT`, `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT_ERROR` and `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`. inconcrete case i sure that task in `RandName()` - it not aligned to 2 bytes

Comment: `L"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"` is not the string you think it is. The RegOpenKeyExW failed, but you didn't check, so you use an uninitialized variable (key) and then bad things happened. It looked enough like a key that it passed the "invalid parameter" check, only to fail later in a much more mysterious way.

Comment: @RaymondChen no. `ObReferenceObjectByHandle` never return status ( STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE, STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH, STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED ) which converted to `ERROR_NOACCESS`. error not frm handle check. the input parameter checked before converting handle to object. this error exactly from invalid (not aligned) pointer. and from not aligned `RandName()` (if code snipet relevant)

Comment: @RbMm Not all registry keys are kernel objects. Remote registry keys are RPC pointers, so if the garbage value looks like a remote registry key, it will get sent down the RPC path, not the kernel path. My guess is that's where the `ERROR_NOACCESS` is coming from.

Comment: @RaymondChen yes, not all keys. but if you pass unaligned `lpValueName` to `RegSetValueEx` we exactly got `ERROR_NOACCESS`. only code owner can check this

Comment: also if run this code exactly - `key` must be 0 after call to `RegOpenKeyExW` and `RegSetValueEx` return `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` but not `ERROR_NOACCESS`

Answer (score 1):

`ERROR_NOACCESS` translated from 3 `NTSTATUS` values:

- `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT`
- `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT_ERROR`
- `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`

in concrete case i am on 100% sure that source of error was `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT` and it raises from [`ProbeForRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-probeforread)

> *If the specified range of memory is not within the user-mode address range, `ProbeForRead` raises the `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` exception.
> If the beginning of the address range is not aligned on the byte
> boundary that is specified by Alignment, ProbeForRead raises the
> `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT` exception.*

`lpValueName` must have the same align as `WCHAR` (so 2 bytes). how `RandName()` aligned is invisible in your code, but probaly task in it align, because i doubt that it not within the user-mode address range